# send values to controller in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I have a nestjs application

```
  async function bootstrap() {
    const token = process.argv[2]); // some value that i want to inject
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,{logger:['debug','verbose']});
    app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard);
    await app.listen(3000);
  }
  bootstrap();
```

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getValue(val : string): string {
    return val;
  }
}
```

How can i pass the token to my AppService ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to call the `AppService` from your `bootstrap`, or are you just wanting to get the value of `process.argv[2]` in the `AppService`? Are you wanting to actually inject it via options, or just access it directly?

Comment: i just want to pass the value to AppService from main.ts, so that i can use it do - for example say generate oauthtoken and use it across multiple controllers in my application

Comment: Why pass it from main? Why not read `process.argv[2]` in the service? Or why not make a provider to inject it via the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it to you in this way.
If you want to use the custom configuration in `@Injectable` constructor you have to make a custom provider to provide your configuration values.

**M1.module.ts**

```js
import { Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { S1Service } from './s1.service';

interface TokenProviderConfig {
  token: string;
}

const S1tokenConfig: TokenProviderConfig = {
  token: 'mySecretToken',
};
export const tokenProvider: Provider = {
  provide: 'TOKEN_CONFIG',
  useValue: S1tokenConfig,
};

@Module({
  providers: [tokenProvider, S1Service],
})
export class M1Module {}
```

In this example, we have a provider object containing our config object and whenever you inject `'TOKEN_CONFIG'` in a service it'll use S1TokenConfig as a value.

**S1Service**

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { S1Config } from './configs';

@Injectable()
export class S1Service {
  constructor(@Inject('TOKEN_CONFIG') private options: S1Config) {
    console.log(options);
  }
}
```

Then you can inject your congiration into `S1Service` with `@Inject` decorator